# Can I use Oracle JDBC 12.1.0.1 (for 12c database) on a Oracle 10g database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, oracle12c

Just a simple question (I guess). Oracle released a new [JDBC driver for Oracle Database 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html) including a Java 7 JDBC driver (ojdbc7 - 12.1.0.1). Here, we've been using **Oracle 10g database** with ojdbc6 for Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4) without any problem. Now, my questions.

If I upgrade my application server to use ojdbc7 for Oracle 12c, is it too risk? Does the Oracle maintains compatibility of their drivers with previous versions?

Comment: If you are not using any specific feature related to oracle 12C, then there will be no problem, as Oracle maintains the backward compatibility. For further details, you should refer their documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  This is officially supported per Oracle.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

Comment: This document has since changed and now states `Questions related to latest version of Oracle Database 12cR1 have been added and all the other references to older versions such as 10g, 9i, 8i have been removed`

Comment: Basically it works, but unofficially, only since Oracle doesn't support Oracle Database 10g.  Treat as YMMV.  If you're not running air traffic control or a nuclear power plant using this configuration, you're probably going to be okay.